# Using a relative image path in Harp Markdown

Tags: image, markdown, harp

I'm putting together a site in Harp which will be composed of multiple topics, written by different contributors, potentially in different languages. My present folder structure is something like this:

```
+public
 |_layout.jade
 +en
  +topic 1
   |_data.json
   |pg1.md
   |pg2.md
   +img
    |pic.png
```

Ideally, to make life easy for them, each contributor will only have to worry about a single folder: the one for their topic. This will also let me keep them as sub-repos, with people only able to interfere with their own work.

The issue I am hitting is that **an image path expressed in Markdown is not relative to the location of the Markdown file** i.e.

**pg1.md**

```
![My image](/img/pic.png "A title")
```

Is translating to

**pg1.html**

```
<img src="/img/pic.png" alt="My image" title="A title">
```

instead of

```
<img src="/en/topic1/img/pic.png" alt="My image" title="A title">
```

**Is there any way I can make my desired behaviour happen, or do I have to get contributors to enter the full path?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A path which starts with a slash is *not* a relative path. Remove the slash from the beginning of the URL:

```
![My image](img/pic.png "A title")
```

Now the image path is relative to the location of the Markdown file.

Note that when a URL starts with a slash, that first slash represents the root of the web server. Therefore any path which starts with a slash is an absolute path. If you want relative paths, you cannot have a path which starts with a slash.

Comment: I forgot the period before the slash... damn.

Thanks for pointing it out! Also, that was the entire cause of my issue.